# Attach pdf view in Jekyll pages

Tags: html, pdf, markdown, jekyll

I have a use case , where I want to view pdf files  in Jekyll pages without downloading it.

For Example : Markdown is like

- Heading 1
- Heading 2

  - pdf view
- Heading 3

  - pdf view

Can you suggest anything like `iframe` etc.. to embed in Jekyll pages

---

I have added below code into my jekyll md files to view pdf , It is working with images and other websites but not for pdf files.(the src path I defined was correct)

**It is downloading the file rather than showing in the iframe.**

```
<div class="pdf-container">
    <iframe src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/pdf/new.pdf" height="315" width="560" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="10">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I am talking about embed into an iframe rather than `link for a download`.

Comment: But images are displaying in the iframe correctly ;with a path `{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/new.pdf` ; I did not define them in a markdown  text format ; I tryed your method it says `Error bad URI`.